# Load image from specific file name in android

Tags: android

I created an app working with saving a screenshot to the USB storage. But I cannot open that image from USB storage. Please help me to solve this issue. This image I don't want to open and keep it in the ImageView but I want to load with the image viewer or another app like we open from Gallery.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:text="Take Screen"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLoad"
    android:text="Take Screen"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

2. **MainActivity.java**

   ```
   btn_load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
           // My image name "restaurant.jpg"
           // image keep in USB storage\restaurant.jpg

       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Have you able to get the image URL where image saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Now this is how to open PDF file from storage or external App

```
// Open from Storage File
public void openFileFromStorage(){

    File file = new File("/sdcard/testpdf/test.pdf");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(intent);
}

// Open External App. How to find Package name install "System Info" in Play Store.
public void openAppExternal(){
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.adobe.reader");
    startActivity(intent);
}

// Open External Website
public static Intent openApp(Context context){
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-class-in-java/",0);
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-class-in-java/"));

    }catch (Exception e){
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-class-in-java/"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) is an open source library that can able to show an image from any source. You can use this in the following steps.

Add this is **build.gradle** file:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

And you **MainActivity**:

```
//Initialize ImageView
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

btn_load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
      //Loading image from any file location into imageView
     String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/restaurent.jpg"; // need to add storage read permission
     Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
          .load(new File(photoPath))
          .into(imageView);
    }
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: btn_load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                        .load(new File("restaurant.jpg"))
                        .into(imageView);
            }
        });

Comment: I already followed your code but didn't show image. Can you explain?

Comment: `restaurant.jpg` is not a full path of your image. Store the image path when you save on USB storage or any directory.

Comment: I open my phone. First-> File Manager->USB storage->restaurant.jpg    So how should I keep-> USB storage\restaurant.jpg   ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I tried but still doesn't work.